# to water (to give an animal water to drink)

Tags: verbs, word-usage

**to give an animal water to drink**
Example: *The horses had been fed and watered.*
Source: Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary 4th Edition

Neither I nor my Australian teacher have ever heard such a usage, but the CALD has another opinion. Who is right?

Comment: It's idiomatic to talk about *watering* animals, particularly horses.

Comment: Hm... can I say so about my dog: Son, go water the doggy?

Comment: ODO claims to source its examples from actual usage. One of the examples in [*verb definition 1.1* of water](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/water) talks about watering *cats*, so I suppose watering *dogs* would work as well. But it sounds a bit odd to my ear - watering *horses* or the generic *animals* sounds better to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Water* as in "to give water to drink" and standing on its own without *feed* is now rare, I would say.

OED gives such a use only from 1940, and from a literary source from an older age. John Buchan actually died in 1940, aged 64.

> 1940   J. Buchan *Memory Hold-the-Door* v. 125   We watered our horses and went supperless to bed.

Even there, *water* is used for livestock rather than domestic animals. More recent citations occur with *feed* ("fed and watered") which is something of a set phrase. There's even a recent Australian citation:

> 1994   *Herald* (Glasgow) (Nexis) 11 June 11   A kindly high-complexioned old chap well fed and watered on beef and claret.
>   2013   *North West Star* (Austral.) (Nexis) 4 Apr. 3   A poor wet season has left graziers¹ unable to feed and water their cattle on their own properties.

*Watered* could be used of more domestic animals ("I didn't leave the farm before I'd watered the dogs") but its primary association with livestock does imply that the animal is not a house-pet².

Note that using *fed and watered* in respect of people (especially described as "a high-complexioned old chap") might be considered a little flippant, although OED does have citations using the expression for armies, where it would be entirely neutral.

---

¹ *grazier* is unusual, but has considerable similarity of construction to *glazier.*

² I could only find one actual example of ODO's *watering cats* sentence which [Lawrence mentioned](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/397788/to-water-to-give-an-animal-water-to-drink#comment944563_397788) (that is, not a quote but the source text), and that was in an online novel which does not seem to me to be particularly well-written: [*The Sager's Creek Chronicles: Keboe's Quandary*](https://www.fictionpress.com/s/1556242/5/The-Sager-s-Creek-Chronicles-Keboe-s-Quandary) by The Universal Storyteller.

Comment: It depends on the situation. If your animals graze all day, and don't need to be fed, then they only need to be watered (unless you have a stream through your pasture).

Answer (score 3):

It's a good dictionary. If they have such a term or definition, it must be based on actual usage in some region or time. So, it must be okay to use it as defined.

But since it's not a commonly heard usage in our daily lives, maybe some people will find it odd, just like you did.

I'd probably avoid saying, "let's go water the cats, dogs etc."